# R SQUARED Formula Based on Conditions

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to insert the R squared formula as follows:

=RSQ(Known_ys, Known_xs) ONLY if row(i)= "YES" and ignore the rest of the data. For instance, the below should calculate RSQ excluding the rows where values in column C ="NO". I tried the following formula, but it didnt work: = {IF(C1:C4="YES",RSQ(B1:B4,A1:A4),"")}

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6.2 | 3.79 | YES |
| 7.2 | 4.56 | NO |
| 8.8 | 6.22 | YES |
| 4.5 | 8.9 | YES |

Comment: I am assuming you do not want to continually mess with the order of the original data? If you don't care about that can simply sort by column C and only apply the RSQ formula to the relevant rows. Another unclean workaround is to create new columns D and E, and use  =IF(C1="YES", A1, "") and =IF(C1="YES", B1, ""), then use RSQ of those two columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ♣SOLVED♣

Here you go (in relation to screenshot below):

```
=RSQ(IF($C$1:$C$4="YES",B1:B4,""),IF(C1:C4="YES",A1:A4,""))
```

[image: Conditional RSQ formula]

Ta,
J

Comment: Thank you very much James! This worked perfectly. I had to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter for the result.

Comment: Sure no prob. Thought you might need to.  Upvote if you can.  Goes a long way! :)

Comment: It doesn't let me upvote it says I need at least 15 reputation to cast  vote